# Would a confession be valid if the priest and penitent can't speak the same language?

Tags: catholicism, confession, language

Say that a person wanted to undergo the sacrament of confession, but the only priest available did not understand any language that the person spoke. Would that be a valid confession? Or do they need to be able to mutually understand each other by speaking the same language?

Comment: Related: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/61845/does-a-roman-catholic-priest-have-to-intellectually-understand-a-confession-in-o